# Filter sub entity in doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

I have two entities that have a one to many relation.

There is a project:

```
class Project
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection|Template[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Template", mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $templates;

    // ...
}
```

And I have templates which might be limited to certain users:

```
class Template
{
    /**
     * @var Project
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="templates")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="project_id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $projectId;

    /**
     * @var array|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userIds;

    // ...
}
```

I now want to get all the projects. But the templates variable of each project should only have the templates that have either userIds NULL or the userId of the current user.

In my repository I already tried the following:

```
public function findForUser(int $userId): array
{
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('p')
       ->from(Project::class, 'p')
       ->leftJoin(Template::class, 't', Join::WITH, 't.project = p.projectId')
       ->where(
           $qb->expr()
              ->isNull('t.userIds')
       )
       ->orWhere('FIND_IN_SET(:userId, t.userIds) > 0');

    $qb->setParameter(':userId', $userId);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->execute();
}
```

But when I call **getTemplates()** I still have all templates in it even the ones the user is not allowed to see.

I also tried instead of `->select('p')` to use `->select('p, t')` as I hoped doctrine would then already fill the templates field with the selected templates but instead it then returns a mixed array of Templates and Projects.

Comment: "But when I call getTemplates() I still have all templates in it" - try calling `findForUser` instead ;)

Comment: `findForUser` is a method of the repository, which as stated above gives me all projects. But when calling `getTemplates()` on each project that was returned by `findForUser` it gives me all templates for that project without them being filtered for the user

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you mean. Are you sure about this approach, though? It seems kind of odd to change the entire project depending on who's knocking. A `getTemplatesForUser($userId)` on the `Project` class seems much more natural.

Comment: Alternatively you could create something like a `ProjectAccess` entity that contains the templates accessible to the user and a link to the project itself. Otherwise you'd be left with a partial object, which is usually quite problematic, especially in the long run. See also https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/partial-objects.html

Comment: I would also like to know answer to this exact problem. Is there a way to filter subentities so that not all of them is loaded into memory when accessed?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you entity schema is not quite optimised for this kind of operation.
You must not save the IDs of the Users in a simple array, but instead, use a ManyToMany relation :

```
class Template
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var User[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="templates")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

Then, the dql query should look something like that :

```
public function findForUser(User $user): array
{
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('p')
       ->from(Project::class, 'p')
       ->leftJoin(Template::class, 't', Join::WITH, 't.project = p.projectId')
       ->leftJoin(User::class, 'u', Join::WITH, 't.users = u.id')
       ->where('COUNT(t.users) = 0')
       ->orWhere('u = :user');

    $qb->setParameter(':user', $user);

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->execute();
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. It just slightly changes the query but the result will be exactly the same as the result set will have the same data in it.